# Laravel mail adds <br /> to the first line of mail and then proper end of lines

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am building a mail for my application but i have been trying to use nl2br in it because people can write in it. Now i have got this piece of code:

```
{!! nl2br($text['text']) !!}
```

I have put it in an array because someone said that works, well it does not really, my result is really strange:

[image]

So it adds 
 add the end of the first line and then adds proper line endings. I have never seen this behaviour before.

This is the complete code in the blade markdown file:

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            <img src="https://www.cpned.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cpned-logo.png" height="75px">
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
    <h1>Goedendag!</h1>

    {!! nl2br($text['text']) !!}


    Met vriendelijke groeten,  {{PHP_EOL}}
      {{PHP_EOL}}
    Het Circulation Practitioners Intranet.
    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} Circulation Practitioners. Alle rechten voorbehouden  <br/>
            Deze mail is gegenereert door het intranet, u kunt hierop niet reageren!
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

The following is in my controller:

```
Mail::to($users)->send(new Reminder($request->subject, array('text' => $request->message)));
```

And then the last file i have got:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Reminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $subject;
    public $text;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $text)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
                ->subject($this->subject)
                ->markdown('emails.reminder');
    }
}
```

I have been struggling with this for hours and I am not abled to spot the problem what is causing this strange behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out to replace

```
{!! nl2br($text['text']) !!}
```

by {!! nl2br(e($text['text'])) !!}

?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-e

Comment: This gives me the same result: https://gyazo.com/1339c0e8989ed53a18699936651cf1d2

Comment: Also see that the font automaticly changes! :o

Comment: This only happens on email? Tested on a browser template, and all was good with your code snippet.

Comment: Yes this only happens here